# How to use FSharp.Management WMI Provider with remote machine

Tags: f#, wmi

I've modified the example script from the FSharp management project to connect to a remote host rather than localhost:

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory (__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__)

#r @"System.Management.dll"
#r @"..\Packages\FSharp.Management.0.3.1\lib\net40\FSharp.Management.dll"
#r @"..\Packages\FSharp.Management.0.3.1\lib\net40\FSharp.Management.WMI.dll"

open FSharp.Management

type Remote = WmiProvider<"remotehost@username:password">
let data = Remote.GetDataContext()
```

Unfortunately I get an error the GetDataContext is not defined on Remote. But if I change the WmiProvider to be WmiProvider<"localhost"> the it works as expected.

I wasn't sure if the login is correct but if I change the username or password to something I know to be incorrect the the WmiProvider line returns an RPC error so I am sure it is logging in correctly.

Answer (score 4):

There are actually two different times that the WmiProvider communicates with the system:  Design Time and Run Time.  In your sample code, you are connecting the WmiProvider to the remote machine at Design Time, meaning it will try to retrieve the WMI "Types" from the remote machine.  You could try using localhost at Design Time, since you said that seems to work, then using the remote machine at Run Time.

An example of using the remote system only at Run Time would be like this:

```
open FSharp.Management

type WmiContext = WmiProvider<"localhost">

let wmiContext = WmiContext.GetDataContext("remoteMachine")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my example I was trying to get the WMI infrastructure working and just get access to the common Windows WMI types. Unfortunately the actual WMI types I need aren't available on localhost as they're part of a remote application.